# IMacos - Extracting element with multiple classes

Tags: extract, imacros

I am using IMacros for extracting txt from a span. Its something like this

`<span class="class1 class2 class3" >Data to Extract</span>`

Now, I am having confusion, how to select the data as it has multiple classes.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:"class1 class2 class3" EXTRACT=TXT
```